# Asp.net mvc FormsAuthentication from a service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm looking at the nerddinner code and in their `AuthenticationController`, they have the following code:

```
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(alias)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "alias");

        FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new
            FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, //version
            userdId.ToString(), // user name
            DateTime.Now,             //creation
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), //Expiration
            createPersistentCookie, //Persistent
            alias); //since Classic logins don't have a "Friendly Name"

        string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
        this.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket));
```

My problem is that I want to move this code into a class that does not inherits from the `Controller` type. The problem with this is the last line of code where it sets the cookie; `Response`, which is specific to `Controller`.

How do I set `encTicket` to a cookie without having access to the controller? Is there a way to use `FormsAuthentication` class itself to d this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to add the encrypted ticket to the browser cookie without using a controller.

```
    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket)
                     {
                         Expires = authTicket.Expiration,
                         Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath
                     };

    if (HttpContext.Current != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have a method in your separate class which returns the cookie so that the only thing the controller has to do is add the cookie to the response. IMO cookie management (adding/deleting) is the responsibility of the controller:

```
var cookie = authService.CreateAuthCookie(userId, alias);
Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
```